# Query Posts in a Predefined Order

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, order

I am using the query_posts function to list a 10 specific posts which lookup by post id.

I have an array which looks like this..

```
Array
(
    [0] => 17983
    [1] => 17932
    [2] => 18030
    [3] => 18016
    [4] => 17972
    [5] => 18013
    [6] => 18035
    [7] => 17959
    [8] => 18020
    [9] => 18039
)
```

I would like to query posts showing it in that specific order, however with my code it shows them in a random order of its own.

Here is the argument I use for query posts:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__in' => $post_ids,
    'numberposts'     => 10,
);
```

$post_ids is the array which I have posted above.

How can I alter my code to query the posts and show them in the order of the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the query is only for a *small number* of posts, then as linked to by Alex you can sort in php. However, this does not scale well.

As suggested by Kovshenin - a better alternative is to use `posts_orderby` filter:

```
$post_ids = array(83,24,106,2283,14);
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__in' => $post_ids,
    'numberposts'     => 10,
);

//Callback to filter the ORDER BY part of the query
function wpse67823_orderby_post_in($orderby, $query){
     global $wpdb;

     //Remove it so it doesn't effect future queries
     remove_filter(current_filter(), __FUNCTION__);

     $post__in = implode(',',$query->get('post__in'));

     return "FIELD( {$wpdb->posts}.ID, $post__in )";
 }

//Add filter and perform query
add_filter('posts_orderby','wpse67823_orderby_post_in',10,2);
$wpse67823_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

### 3.5+

WordPress 3.5 will see an additional value accepted by `WP_Query` for `orderby`: 'post__in'. See this trac ticket: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13729

Comment: Thanks for the code, although I have tried it and also made edits to it, I am unable to get it to query the posts in the order of the array (Sorry to be a pain)

Comment: I've edited my answer, the above works for me.

Comment: Just tested again now, it does work :D
I think it was an issue with the while statment I had. Thanks for the help Stephen!

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Stephen Harris answer, for Wordpress 3.5+ the easiest option seems to be ordering by `post__in`.

Here is the example:

```
$post_ids = Array(12, 15, 18, 8, 10, 5);

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post__in' => $post_ids,
  'numberposts' => 10,
  'orderby' => 'post__in'
);
$posts = WP_Query($args); // or any other method that uses WP_Query args e.g. get_posts()

// as a result you will get posts in order: 12, 15, 18, 8, 10, 5
```

I've tested that myself on a Wordpress 4.7 site and it works as expected.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It doesn't reply on filters, it just uses the built in orderby feature.

Comment: Best and simple answer, should be accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to hijack the resulting SQL query during `posts_orderby` and use MySQL's `ORDER BY FIELD()` function with a comma-separated list from your array. Here's more info about the `FIELD` function: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/

I did this quite some time ago when I had Sphinx return a list of post IDs ordered by relevance, so I had to select them with `WP_Query` in that very same order. `FIELD()` during the `posts_orderby` filter worked like a charm.

Also, if you're using `query_posts` to alter the main query, it's not the best way to do it. @Alex mentioned `WP_Query`, which is not really different from `query_posts` and is also a bad way to (make it seem like you) alter the main query.

The correct way would be to use the `pre_get_posts` action, and change the passed in by reference `$query` object. You can learn more about pre_get_posts here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Hope that's helpful. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, and you can use the php `implode` function to convert your array into a comma-separated list of IDs which you can use in that `FIELD` query :)

Comment: The query isn't the main query, its used for a charting system on the sidebar. I've had a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby. By adding this function though its going to alter the main query rather than the sidebar query isnt it?

Comment: @Imran you can target the specific query by adding the filter immediately before the `WP_Query` and removing it again afterwards.

Comment: @StephenHarris: Can you show me an example of this?

Comment: @Imran, if you indeed need a secondary loop, then `new WP_Query` or `get_posts` will work best. `posts_orderby` gets called on every query. As Stephen suggested, you can add the filter before running your query and remove it soon after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler Workaround to achieve this, simply create a custom field for each one of these posts with the same name ans set your desired order, ex:

- for post with id =  17983 set a custom field named my_custom_order =
  1
- for post with id =  18030 set a custom field named my_custom_order =
  2
- for post with id =  18016 set a custom field named my_custom_order = 3
- you get the point

then in your query simply order by that custom field:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__in' => $post_ids,
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'meta_key' => 'my_custom_order',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

**Note:**
Once you do that (set the custom field for these posts) you can remove the        `'post__in' => $post_ids,` parameter since only posts with the custom field of `my_custom_order` will be queried from the database.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, don't use `query_posts()`, use [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Second, change your array to just the post ids.

from:

```
[0] => 17983
[1] => 17932
```

to

```
array( 17983, 17932 )
```

**EDIT**: Look [HERE](http://kuttler.eu/code/order-posts-in-a-wp_query-manually/) for a reference.

Comment: Huh? How exactly is `[0] => 17983, ...` different from `array( 17983, ... )` :) The former is just a `print_r` of the latter.